# Как проверить возвращаемый объект?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая функция:

```
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
    img.addEventListener('error', reject); // don't forget this one
    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

Как сделать чтобы при наличии картинки происходило это :

```
$('.wrapper').append('<div class="block" data-id="' + adress + i + ".jpg" + '">' + i + '</div>');
```

Comment: вам не кажется, что задавать вопрос на каждом шаге некрасиво? Может попытаетесь подумать.

Comment: почитайте о промайсах и внимательно посмотрите на функцию. у вас всё готово, стоит только немного подумать, как сказал @ArchDemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loadImage(url).then(address => $('.wrapper').append('<div class="block" data-id="' + address + i + ".jpg" + '">' + i + '</div>'))
```